# Automatically minifies js and css files on the fly and checks for any changes on the source files without using gulp or webpack

Tags: javascript, php

Is this possible with javascript or any other programming languages to do concatenate js or css files into one minified file.

Answer (score 0):

- To minify HTML, try [HTMLMinifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier)
- To minify CSS, try [CSSNano](https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano) and [csso](https://github.com/css/csso).
- To minify JavaScript, try [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2).